# remove charcaters from string

Tags: python, string

i need a function `remove()` that removes characters from a string.

This was my first approach:

```
def remove(self, string, index):
    return string[0:index] + string[index + 1:]

def remove_indexes(self, string, indexes):
    for index in indexes:
        string = self.remove(string, index)
    return string
```

Where I pass the indexes I want to remove in an array, but once I remove a character, the whole indexes change.

Is there a more pythonic whay to do this. it would be more preffarable to implement it like that:

```
"hello".remove([1, 2])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont know about a "pythonic" way, but you can achieve this. If you can ensure that in `remove_indexes` the indexes are always sorted, then you may do this

```
def remove_indexes(self, string, indexes):
    for index in indexes.reverse():
        string = self.remove(string, index)
    return string
```

If you cant ensure that then just do

```
def remove_indexes(self, string, indexes):
    for index in indexes.sort(reverse=True):
        string = self.remove(string, index)
    return string
```

Answer (score 2):

I think below code will work for you.It removes the indexes(that you want to remove from string) and returns joined string formed with remaining indexes.

```
def remove_indexes(string,indexes):
    return "".join([string[i] for i in range(len(string)) if i not in indexes])

remove_indexes("hello",[1,2])
```

Answer (score 1):

The most pythonic way would be to use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html). The danger with your indexing approach is that the string you are passing in may have variable length, and therefore you would be removing parts of the string unintentionally.

Lets say you wanted to remove all numbers from a string

```
import re

s = "This is a string with s0m3 numb3rs in it1 !"
num_reg = re.compile(r"\d+")  # catches all digits 0-9
re.sub(num_reg , "**", s)  # substitute numbers in `s` with "**"
>>> "This is a string with s**m** numb**rs in it** !"
```

This way, you define an general expression that may appear regularly in a string (a "regular expression" or regex), and you can quickly and reliably replace all instances of that regex in the string.

Answer (score 1):

You  cannot add attribute to `built-in` types you will have an error like this:

```
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'str'
```

You can create a `class` that inherit the `str` and add this method:

```
class String(str):
    def remove(self, index):
        if isinstance(index, list):
            # order the index to remove the biggest first
            for i in sorted(index, reverse=True):
                self = self.remove(i)
            return self
        return String(self[0:index] + self[index + 1:])

s = String("hello")
print(s.remove([0, 1]))
```

You want change in place you need to create a new type for example:

```
 class String:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._str = value

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        """ delegate to str"""
        return getattr(self._str, item)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        """ support slicing"""
        return String(self._str[item])

    def remove(self, indexex):
        indexes = indexex if isinstance(indexex, list) else [indexex]
        # order the index to remove the biggest first
        for i in sorted(indexes, reverse=True):
            self._str = self._str[0:i] + self._str[i + 1:]
        # change in place should return None
        return None

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._str)

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self._str)


s = String("hello")
s.remove([0, 1])
print(s.upper())    # delegate to str class
print(s[:1])    # support slicing
print(list(x for x in s))    # it's iterable
```

But still missing a other magic method to act like a real `str` class. like `__add__ , __mult___, .....`

If you want a class like `str` but have a `remove` method that changes the instance itself **you need to create your own mutable type**, `str` are **primitive immutable type** and `self = self.remove(i)` will not really change the variable because it's just changing the reference of `self` argument to another `object`, but the reference `s` is still pointing to the same object created by `String("hello")`.

Comment: ```i = String("hello")   
    i.remove([0, 1])   
    print(i)``` is not working. Since `self = self.remove(i)` is not editing the variable.

Comment: sorry about the extra code, the point is you cannot add attribute to `built-in str` type so you can't add any method.

Comment: Yeah I should return String type sorry about that

Comment: `str` are primitive type you cannot change them in place.

Comment: Hope this help you, the problem is that str are immutable you need to create a new class that act like str you can take a look at my edits but may be there is a better solution than this I really don't know for now